# Syncing linting and configuration files between git repositories

Tags: git, github, configuration, synchronization, repository

I'm trying to keep my root configuration files ([.editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/), [.prettierrc.js](https://prettier.io/), [.eslintrc.js](https://eslint.org/), [release.config.js](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/), [.browserslistrc](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist), ...) synced between multiple repos (10 at the moment). I considered switching to a monorepo architecture as this would also bring other benefits with it, but [tooling](https://github.com/microsoft/rushstack/issues/1659) [still](https://github.com/pmowrer/semantic-release-monorepo/issues/51) [remains](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/193) [insufficient](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2437).
Is it possible to write a GitHub Action that automatically pushes changes to any of these files in one repo to all the others? I've heard a post-commit hook is what I'm looking for. Is this a scalable approach? (e.g. will this behave reliably with 20, 30 synced repos?) Are there any resources on how such a script should be written?
Is there another way I can keep my configuration files synced? I want to enforce the same branching model, linting and testing rules across all my repositories.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't actually implemented this but creating an npm package of your common js configs/rules could work. Each repo would then need to import that package.

```
extends: '@yourDomain/lint-rules'
```

Comment: This could work. ESLint propose that. They call it „Shareable Configs“. More infos here https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/shareable-configs